# How do I use node-mongodb-native to connect to Heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku

I'm getting really confused over how to connect to MongoLab on Heroku.
To connect using the uri to Heroku, I was trying to follow this example:
http://experiencecraftsmanship.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/heroku-node-js-mongodb-featuring-the-native-driver/

I looked at both his web.js and deep.js. 
They both do something like:

```
connect.createServer(
    require( 'connect-jsonrpc' )( contacts )
).listen( port );
```

But then only the database query in 'contacts' get passed into this server then?
Am I allowed to do multiple connect.createServer for each of my database access method?

The following is part of my code when just connecting to MongoDB locally. I am unsure of how to modify it to connect to MongoLab on Heroku.

Can someone teach me how to modify my code to connect? Or explain some of these concepts? I have no idea why the author of that website I posted used so many callbacks to do a database call, when my approach below seems straightforward enough (I'm new to JavaScript, not good with callbacks).

```
var app = module.exports = express.createServer(
  form({ keepExtensions: true })
);

var Db = require('mongodb').Db;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;
var client = new Db('blog', new Server('127.0.0.1', 27017, {}));

var posts;
var getAllPosts = function(err, collection) {
  collection.find().toArray(function(err, results) {
    posts = results;
    console.log(results);
    client.close();
  });
}


app.get('/', function(req, response) {
  client.open(function(err, pClient) {
    client.collection('posts', getAllPosts);
  });

  // some code
  response.render('layout', { posts: posts, title: 'Raymond', contentPage: 'blog' });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You connect to your mongolab database (so you can't create a new "blog" database). process.env.MONGOLAB_URI includes the database name as well. See your mongolab uri:

```
heroku config | grep MONGOLAB_URI
```

It looks like: `mongodb://heroku_app123456:password@dbh73.mongolab.com:27737/heroku_app123456`

On github there is [an example how to connect and retrieve data from a mongolab database](https://github.com/p15martin/BlogMongoDbNativeDriver/blob/master/web.js).

Comment: I was looking at that example.
Can I call connect.createServer( ... ) multiple times? Because I define multiple url endpoints that require access to the database. I'm also not sure how to pass in my own parameters from the url parameters.

Comment: You don't need to createServer for every url endpoint. To handle database operations you could create a kind of Provider. See an example of ["ArticleProvider" on how-to-node blog](http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb)

Answer (score 2):

Use "connect" to connect to mongo, instead of defining db, server, client:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var database = null;

var mongostr = [YOUR MONGOLAB_URI];

mongo.connect(mongostr, {}, function(error, db)
    {       
            console.log("connected, db: " + db);

            database = db;

            database.addListener("error", function(error){
            console.log("Error connecting to MongoLab");

            });
});
```